# Cannot import svg file to Android Studio properly

Tags: android, svg, adobe-illustrator, android-vectordrawable

I can't convert my .svg file to android studio properly.

[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E51Gx.png)

[This is how it looks like after using a SVG to vector-drawable Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA3YW.png)

And when I try to conver it directly into Android Studio, then I get a In "
ERROR@ line 2 < defs > is not supported

Doesn anyone know why this happens and what I can do about it?
Are there any alternatives I can use to get a scalable good looking image?

I can't find my mistake and I would appreciate any help. Thanks.
Ps. I'm using illustrator cc 2017

Comment: Vector drawables do not handle everything in SVG, and your image does not appear to be one of the defined icon formats (e.g., action bar icons).

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Use PNGs or WebPs.

Comment: Your SVG may be convertible, to something that Android Studio accepts. But without seeing it, we can only guess.  Please post the SVG - or at least a cut down version of it that shows the problem (for example just the hair)